# CodeIgniter one query multiple statements

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter, and when an `insert_batch` does not fully work (number of items inserted different from the number of items given), I have to do the inserts again, using insert ignore to maximize the number that goes through the process without having errors for existing ones.
When I use this method, the kind of data I'm inserting does not need strict compliance between the number of items given, and the number put in the database. Maximize is the way.

What would be the correct way of a) using `insert_batch` as much as possible b) when it fails, using a workaround, while minimizing the number of unnecessary requests?

Thanks

Comment: You could split the array passed to insert_batch and call it many times based on the split result. You probably know how much queries are completed, based on that you can decide the size of the split.

Comment: I was thinking about extending insert_batch to make a "max_insert_batch" function, which would do the same as insert_batch, adding this : 
each time it calls _insert_batch, 
if $this->affected_rows() != $batch_size (cf insert_batch), and if $batch_size > 1, 
you call it recursively with the same block of data, and a batch_size = floor(batch_size / 2), eventually with a "ignore" option.

That would allow to "retry when needed" while avoiding to when not.
Your opinion ?

Comment: imho - you should post your code what you've tried because it is a bit problematic to discuss this topic in theory

Comment: @sintakonte : it is a theoretical question, i'm currently thinking about a way to maximize a process efficiency, i didn't write any code for now.

Answer (score 0):

AS @q81 mentioned, you would split the batches (as you see fit or depending on system resources) like this:

```
$insert_batch = array();
$maximum_items = 100;

$i = 1;
while ($condition == true) {
    // code to add data into $insert_batch
    // ...

    // insert the batch every n items
    if ($i == $maximum_items) {
        $this->db->insert_batch('table', $insert_batch); // insert the batch
        $insert_batch = array(); // empty batch array
        $i = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}

// the last $insert_batch
if ($insert_batch) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('table', $insert_batch);
}
```

**Edit:**

while insert batch [already splits the batches](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1588), the reason why you have `"number of items inserted different from the number of items given"` might be because the allowed memory size is reached. this happened to me too many times.

Comment: I don't see the point in splitting this way : insert_batch already does that (or i didn't fully understand your answer).

Answer (score 0):

The Correct way of inserting data using `insert_batch` is :

CI_Controller :

```
public function add_monthly_record()
{
    $date               = $this->input->post('date');
    $due_date           = $this->input->post('due_date');
    $billing_date       = $this->input->post('billing_date');
    $total_area         = $this->input->post('total_area');
    $comp_id            = $this->input->post('comp_id');
    $unit_id            = $this->input->post('unit_id');
    $percent            = $this->input->post('percent');
    $unit_consumed      = $this->input->post('unit_consumed');
    $per_unit           = $this->input->post('per_unit');
    $actual_amount      = $this->input->post('actual_amount');
    $subsidies_from_itb = $this->input->post('subsidies_from_itb');
    $subsidies          = $this->input->post('subsidies');

    $data = array();
    foreach ($unit_id as $id => $name) {
      $data[] = array(
                    'date'               => $date,
                    'comp_id'            => $comp_id,
                    'due_date'           => $due_date,
                    'billing_date'       => $billing_date,
                    'total_area'         => $total_area,
                    'unit_id'            => $unit_id[$id],
                    'percent'            =>$percent[$id],
                    'unit_consumed'      => $unit_consumed[$id],
                    'per_unit'           => $per_unit[$id],
                    'actual_amount'      => $actual_amount[$id],
                    'subsidies_from_itb' => $subsidies_from_itb[$id],
                    'subsidies'          => $subsidies[$id],
                ); 
    };


    $result = $this->Companies_records->add_monthly_record($data);

    //return from model
    $total_affected_rows = $result[1];
    $first_insert_id = $result[0];

   //using last id 
    if ($total_affected_rows) {
        $count = $total_affected_rows - 1;
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
            $id = $first_insert_id + $x;
            $invoice = 'EBR' . date('m') . '/' . date('y') . '/' . str_pad($id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $field = array(
                'invoice_no' => $invoice,
            );
            $this->Companies_records->add_monthly_record_update($field,$id);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($result); 
}
```

CI_Model :

```
public function add_monthly_record($data)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('monthly_record', $data);
     $first_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
     $total_affected_rows = $this->db->affected_rows();
    return [$first_insert_id, $total_affected_rows];
}
```

Comment: copying some random code and hope it will be here forever, doesn't qualify as an aswer...